# Does flow control impact performance in js

Tags: javascript, performance, control-flow

Does checking if a predetermined boolean is true or false impact performance? Or does such code get optimized into 2 different implementations (considering V8 & SpiderMonkey)?

Example 1

```
let predeterminedBool = Math.random() < .5

callsCalbacksOften(() => {
  if (predeterminedBool) console.log("Task A")
  else console.log("Task B")
})
```

Example 2

```
let predeterminedBool = Math.random() < .5
let chosenCallback

if (predeterminedBool) chosenCallback = () => {
  console.log("Task A")
}
else chosenCallback = () => {
  console.log("Task B")
}

callsCalbacksOften(chosenCallback)
```

Example gets very bulky with big (in terms of lines of code) Tasks. Resulting in basically copied code (execpt for this one condition). Though Example 2 seems more efficient. So, is Example 1 slower than Example 2? If yes, by any significant amount? Or is this just perception by the syntax of js?

PS: How well does this translate to other languages where siilar conceps can be applied (like java)?

Comment: you could test the perfomance here: http://jsben.ch/

Comment: Try to benchmark it! And try a third version where you make `predeterminedBool` a `const`, so that the engine can optimise it right.

Comment: "*Is Example 1 slower than Example 2?*" - yes, because it does more work. Or relies on the optimiser to do more work. "*If yes, by any significant amount?*" - no. It's just a single boolean constant condition, and branch predictors are really good.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.